# How to extract from a file lines that don't have any of 4 strings?

Tags: awk, grep

I have a file like this:

```
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT A1  A1_FREQ FIRTH?  TEST    OBS_CT  BETA    SE  Z_OR_F_STAT P   ERRCODE
1   740284  rs61770167  C   T   T   0.0031746   N   ADD 21420   NA  NA  NA  NA  .
1   740284  rs61770167  C   T   T   0.0031746   N   DOMDEV  21420   NA  NA  NA  NA  RANK_DEFICIEN
1   740284  rs61770167  C   T   T   0.0031746   N   GENO_2DF    21420   NA  NA  NA  NA  CORR_TOO_HIGH
1   754433  rs150578204 G   A   A   0.00400223  N   ADD 21488   NA  NA  NA  NA  CORR_TOO_HIGH
1   754433  rs150578204 G   A   A   0.00400223  N   DOMDEV  21488   NA  NA  NA  NA  VIF_TOO_HIGH
1   754433  rs150578204 G   A   A   0.00400223  N   GENO_2DF    21488   NA  NA  NA  NA  .
1   754458  rs142682604 G   T   T   0.00397897  N   ADD 21488   NA  NA  NA  NA  CORR_TOO_HIGH
1   754458  rs142682604 G   T   T   0.00397897  N   DOMDEV  21488   NA  NA  NA  NA  CORR_TOO_HIGH
1   754458  rs142682604 G   T   T   0.00397897  N   GENO_2DF    21488   NA  NA  NA  NA  UNFINISHED
```

How do I extract only lined that don't have any of those 4 strings:CORR_TOO_HIGH,VIF_TOO_HIGH,RANK_DEFICIENT,UNFINISHED. Or to put this in another words the 15th column can have only "." and not other strings.

File is space separated.

I know how to do this for one string, but I don't know how to do this for multiple strings:

```
grep -v 'CORR_TOO_HIGH' nephropathy_chr1.pheno.glm.logistic.hybrid > file.out
```

Expected output for this example is:

```
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT A1  A1_FREQ FIRTH?  TEST    OBS_CT  BETA    SE  Z_OR_F_STAT P   ERRCODE
1   740284  rs61770167  C   T   T   0.0031746   N   ADD 21420   NA  NA  NA  NA  .
1   754433  rs150578204 G   A   A   0.00400223  N   GENO_2DF    21488   NA  NA  NA  NA  .
```

Comment: After all the questions you've asked and got answers for recently [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/401868/anamaria) and at [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12266202/anamaria), not to mention a quick glance at the man page, I really think you could have figured out for yourself that the syntax for `the 15th column can have only "."` is `$15 == "."`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '$15=="."||NR<2' file
```

- `NR<2` prints header
- `$15=="."` prints every other line with `.` in 15th column.

Answer (score 1):

Like this :

```
awk '$15 !~ /^(CORR_TOO_HIGH|VIF_TOO_HIGH|RANK_DEFICIENT|UNFINISHED)$/' file
```

Comment: Based on their output, I think the OP _wants_ the lines with `.` as the 15th column.

Comment: This is unclear with 'don't have "." in the 15th column'

Comment: Yes, very unclear. I am assuming that was a typo though since the output suggests so.